# How can I show fields of the NTFS "File Summary Information" in the Windows file explorer?

Tags: file, registry, explorer, summary, ntfs

I have the possibility to write and read additional NTFS "File Summary Information" to any file, let's say a txt file. Unfortunately they do not show up in the "Details" tab of the Windows file explorer. I found some tricks for the registry but they didn't work yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the alternate data stream "Document Summary Information"?